# How to create mongoose schema with array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have this json:

```
{
    "data": [
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Sample test",
        "description": "this is a sample test",
        "category": "tests",
        "points": 100,
        "startDate"​:​"2018-02-15 00:00:00"​,
        "endDate"​:​"2018-02-22 00:00:00"​,
        "isActive"​:​true​,
        "alreadyAnswered"​:​false​,
        "questions"​:[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "What is your name",
                "type": "text",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "What is your favorite color",
                "type": "select",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "Red",
                        "value": "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "text": "Blue",
                        "value": "blue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I need to create this json into mongo database so I can get it via my node application.

This is my current schema:

```
let TestSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    category: String,
    points: Number,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    isActive: Boolean,
    alreadyAnswered: Boolean
});
```

My greatest problem is I don't know how to add other objects into my schema to replicate the json, in MySQL I would do it with a hasmany relationship and add the correspondent id into the questions and options, but in this case I need to do via Mongo(create the json and get it via a route).

How can I do that programatically?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
data: [
    id: String, //or number, whatever you need
    name: String,
    description: String,
    category: String,
    points: Number,
    startDate​:​ Date,
    endDate​: ​Date,
    isActive​: ​Boolean​,
    alreadyAnswered​:​ Boolean​,
    questions:[{
            id: String, //or again, number
            text: String,
            type: String,
            options: [
                {
                    id: String, //or number
                    text: String,
                    value: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

This should be schema for this JSON

Comment: How I can define for this type:  `device_meta: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to `@Prathamesh More`:

```
device_meta: [{
   // For example
   device_name: String,
   ID: Number
}]
```

Arrays implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array), so no need for a `default` keyword